# Apache drill on ec2 cluster connection timeout

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timeout, apache-drill

I am trying to get drill running on a 3 node cluster made up of ec2 instances. I configured 
the drill-override.conf file so that it can connect to my zookeeper cluster. and then started
drillbit.sh on all three nodes, checked the status, and they were running. I try to open drill
using drill-conf and the first time it works and I ensure it can see all three drillbits
by using:

```
    SELECT * FROM sys.drillbits;
```

and it shows all three drillbits properly. However, I reboot the cluster and try to retry to process
and this is the error that I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-<private IP> bin]$ ./drill-conf
Error: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: <private DNS>/<private IP>:31010 (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: <private DNS>/<private IP>:31010
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:159)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:64)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
        at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
        at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:167)
        at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:213)
        at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1083)
        at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1015)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:742)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:528)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:596)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:375)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:268)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: <private DNS>/<private IP>:31010
        at org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient$FutureHandler.connectionFailed(DrillClient.java:448)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClient$ConnectionMultiListener$ConnectionHandler.operationComplete(BasicClient.java:237)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClient$ConnectionMultiListener$ConnectionHandler.operationComplete(BasicClient.java:200)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:603)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:563)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:460)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:254)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: <private DNS>/<private IP>:31010
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:47)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClient$ConnectionMultiListener$ConnectionHandler.operationComplete(BasicClient.java:213)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: ip-172-31-24-19.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.24.19:31010
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:458)
        ... 6 more
apache drill 1.6.0
"the only truly happy people are children, the creative minority and drill users"
0: jdbc:drill:>
```

I've looked this up in a few places and tried out their solutions one of which was making sure
/etc/hosts is configured properly and that didn't fix it. Is there anything else I can try to solve the
issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Had to make sure my security group for the ec2 instaqnces were configured properly by letting in the correct traffic to port 31010.